# How can I reference an List<string> object's position index without searching for first occurrence?

Tags: c#, linq, list, indexing

I am trying to create an XML document using Linq and need to reference the index within a list of each object. At the moment all I can find is the **IndexOf(s)** method which just returns the first occurrence of s, rather the position of any s given. This creates a problem when the List contains multiple copies of the same value.

```
var commands = listProcedure.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();

var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("commands",
                commands.Select(s => new XElement("command", s, new XAttribute("id", commands.IndexOf(s)))
                )));
```

Comment: Commands is a list of "string", you can write your own IndexOf extension method that accepts a predicate to match the right method.

Comment: Select has an overload for taking the index: `Select((s, index) => ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
var commands = listProcedure.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();

var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("commands",
                commands.Select( (s, idx) => 
                    new XElement("command", s, new XAttribute("id", idx))
                )));
```

Answer (score 0):

For LINQ look at SELECTMANY - sorry can't be more help with detail but hopefully a pointer in the right direction.